# Connect to Excel with Ado

Tags: sql, excel, ado, firebird

im' trying to connect to Firebird Database using Ado:

```
Sub Test()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection

End Sub
```

but i get compile error: `User-defined type not defined`

Why?

I've managed to connect with database using Excel's Microsoft Query. And i have Firebird Driver..

Comment: ¿Did you add the needed references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the vba code you need to check the reference for ADO

[image: references]

then check the ado reference.... I've checked 2.8 here for backward compatibility for use with  Excel 2003.

[image: reference list]